# unexpected '>' with money gem on Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, currency

I am using ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.17

gem 'money'

Gemfile.lock uses money (6.0.1)

But while running passenger it shows error

```
/home/debadattap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@syr/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:153: syntax error, unexpected '>'
        fn = -> { @rates[rate_key_for(from, to)] = rate }
               ^
/home/debadattap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@syr/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:153: odd number list for Hash
/home/debadattap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@syr/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:179: syntax error, unexpected '>'
        fn = -> { @rates[rate_key_for(from, to)] }
               ^
/home/debadattap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@syr/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:179: odd number list for Hash
/home/debadattap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@syr/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:212: syntax error, unexpected '>'
        fn = -> {
               ^
/home/debadattap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@syr/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:220: odd number list for Hash
/home/debadattap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@syr/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:222: syntax error, unexpected kUNLESS, expecting '}'
          unless file.nil?
                ^
/home/debadattap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@syr/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:225: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting kEND
/home/debadattap/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@syr/gems/money-6.0.1/lib/money/bank/variable_exchange.rb:257: syntax error, unexpected '>'
        fn = -> {
               ^
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails? Maybe that specific Rails implementation fixes this error.

Comment: @SebastianWramba.. thanks for the suggestion , I have not tried it as the application is old and sometimes fails with unsupported gems.
Let me to try with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That version of the Money gem is using Ruby 1.9+ syntax so isn't going to work with Ruby 1.8.7  you're using unfortunately. The changelog for the gem mentions 1.8.7 support in 6.0.0 so you could try that version of the gem instead.

https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: thanks for pointing the money version.. It seems it is working.